# How to test if a MarshalByRefObject is valid?

Tags: c#, activator, marshalbyrefobject

In a VS2010 C# project we have a class derived from a MarshalByRefObject and we use Activator.GetObject to set it. We are using this derived class to talk to a machine across the network.

Sometimes the target machine is on and able to be pinged but it isn't running the program we want to talk to, this causes a 30 second wait followed by an exception. Is there a way to tell if my derived MarshalByRefObject is valid?

Currently a try/catch is handling this situation, but the 30 second wait is not acceptable.

Comment: can you put what the exact error msg as well as show how you are Marshalling the code..? are you Doing any Tunneling .. Tunel Claass

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IP:Port" I'm don't believe we are using any tunneling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try having a Task call a Ping() method, and use the explicit timeout on the task...

```
Task task = new Task(() => { try { obj.Ping(); } catch {} });
task.Start();
if(!task.Wait(1000)) throw new TimeoutException();
// handle other task exceptions etc
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not what I was looking for but it has drastically reduced wait times.

Comment: @LightLabyrinth note: you should probably have a try/catch **inside** the delegate

Comment: It appears this solution causes a "SocketException was unhandled by user code"-"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IP:port". This is inside a try/catch. Using google it seems this is occurring in another thread so I cannot catch it... I tried putting a try/catch inside the delegate with no luck.

Comment: @Light it is Task(() => { try { obj.Ping(); } catch {} }); right?